# RedirectMatch escaping AMP?

Tags: regex, apache

I have a condition like this:

```
RedirectMatch ^/g/(.*) https://www.${APACHE_HOSTNAME}/folder1/?ec=$1&ea=EBH&el=GCC
```

So when I do CURL to that virtualhost running that condition
like this `https://www.example.com/g/1234`

it gives me back this:

```
https://www.example.com/folder1/?ec=1234&amp;ea=EBH&amp;el=GCC
```

Is there a way to escape this ? Why it's substituting the "&amp ;" ?

Many Thanks !

Comment: Try this: `RedirectMatch ^/g/(.*) /folder1/?ec=$1&ea=EBH&el=GCC` and test in a new browser.

Comment: what's the difference ? You can't have the variable inside ?

Comment: nope, same resut.

Comment: Edit your question and post complete .htaccess